# Run-time 438 on searching and pasting gender

Tags: excel, html, vba

I am running the following code that takes a value from column A, searches it on the URL: https://gender-api.com and returns the gender of the person and pastes it in column B.

I get a

> run-time error 438

when running the code. Please help.

```
Sub URL_Get_Gender_Query()
    strSearch = Range("a4")
    With ActiveSheet.QueryTables.Add(Connection:="URL;https://gender-api.com?SearchText=" & strSearch & "&safe=active", _Destination:=Range("b4")) 
        '^ Run-time error 438 here

        .BackgroundQuery = True
        .TablesOnlyFromHTML = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        .SaveData = True
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: What is `ActiveSheet.Gender`? A sheet does not have the property `Gender`! Where did you get this code from?

Comment: I got this from a work mate who copied off a forum site. I am still a VBA newbie so bear with me

Comment: Okay have rectified ActiveSheet.Gender section

Comment: @MunasheZanza Right, so you don't get the error anymore. Voting to close.

Comment: Which line do you get the "run-time error 438" on now?  Still on the `QueryTables.Add`?

Comment: Yes on that line @YowE3K

Answer (score 1):

Here's another way to do it, using the [`WinHttpRequest` object](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa384106(v=vs.85).aspx):

```
Dim httpRequest As Object
Dim url As String
Dim i As Long
Dim jsonResponse As String

Set httpRequest = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
url = "https://gender-api.com/get?name=elizabeth" ' For example
httpRequest.Open "POST", url, False
httpRequest.send
jsonResponse = httpRequest.ResponseText
MsgBox jsonResponse
```

Comment: It is not working for me. Did it run succesfully when you did it?

Comment: It did. Define "not working"?  The nice thing about this approach is that you don't pollute your sheet with all kinds of noise from the query, as you do with `ActiveSheet.QueryTables`. You just get a simple JSON string that is then straightforward to parse.

Comment: I am getting compile error: invalid outside procedure

Comment: Okay... then put the code inside a procedure. I suggest you do a web search for "compile error: invalid outside procedure". Try to solve the problem yourself before asking for help.

Comment: okay I have solved procedure issue the issue now is how do I get this code to look up each value in column and paste in the adjacent cell.

Comment: Try something, then come back with a question about the specific problem you're having.